# Cannot implicitly convert type System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<Prog.tblName> to Prog.tblName

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to import some records from Access to SQL server using LINQ to SQL, and I received the error in the subject at "select new tblName" (select is underlined) in the following code:

```
        OdbcConnection myconnection = new OdbcConnection("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=" + this.txtFullPath.Text);
        OdbcDataAdapter myadapter = new OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Name", myconnection);
        DataSet myCustomersDS = new DataSet();
        myadapter.Fill(myCustomersDS, "Name");

        //LINQ
        iMISDataContext db = new iMISDataContext();

        // inserting multiple items
        tblName toInsert =
            from row in myCustomersDS.Tables["Name"].AsEnumerable()
            select new tblName
            {
                ID = row.Field<string>("ID"),
                ORG_CODE = row.Field<string>("ORG_CODE"),
                MEMBER_TYPE = row.Field<string>("MEMBER_TYPE"),
                //... and rest of the columns (lots of columns)
            };
        db.tblNames.InsertAllOnSubmit(toInsert);
        db.SubmitChanges();
```

There is another error also at the 2nd last line:
The type arguments for method 'System.Data.Linq.Table.InsertAllOnSubmit(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Thank you,
Steven

Comment: What's the signature of `InsertAllOnSubmit`?

Answer (score 1):

When you query to do projection over rows in `myCustomersDS.Tables["Name"]` you are actually selecting some objects not a single one. So change

```
// inserting multiple items
        tblName toInsert =
            from row in myCustomersDS.Tables["Name"].AsEnumerable()
            .......
```

to:

```
// inserting multiple items
        var toInsert =
            from row in myCustomersDS.Tables["Name"].AsEnumerable()
            .....
```

Comment: Thank you. I had var before and it underlined for me, and I thought it was a variable declaration, but I know Pascal or Delphi is using "var" to declare variables, so I replaced with the type. What does var mean here? Thanks, Steven

Comment: var is a shortcut for variable type. Here it can be replaced to EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow>